# NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in info.plist string value disappearing on build. Ionic framework, Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm not quite sure I'm running into this issue but when I build for the ios platform my value for the key NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in my info.plist disappears.  Thus I am left with this is in my info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

I am using ngCordova $geoLocation for determing latitude and longitude.

Any one else have this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? As in this? : https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

Comment: or this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Comment: I'm using this one: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/   The npm plugin and the one from ngcordova are the same.

Comment: ah oky, i'll get back to you,

Comment: Ok, I got them to stay by configuring the plugin's xml ios section to include the keys and their respective values then including them in the .plist file.  But now, every time I open the application it asks permission with a message "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXXX/XXXXXXX/appname/www/index.html" Would Like To Use Your Current Location.  How would I customize this message?

Comment: @Larcerax I solved my problem.  Apparently, setting the $timeout function with an appropriate delay stops the alert.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got them to stay by configuring the plugin's xml ios section to include the keys and their respective values then including them in the .plist file.